# Validate UserIdentityToken with Javascript

Tags: validation, outlook-addin, office-js, access-token, signing

How do i use javascript to validate the token from `Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync()`. Are there any javascript libraries for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is documentation on validating an identity token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/validate-an-identity-token). We do not supply a JS library.

Comment: Yes ...I however noticed that the discovery url is in the JWT Token. That seems strange if we want to verify authenticity of signing. Could this url change...should i expect that its the same for all exchange server tokens?

Comment: The url can be different for users with mailbox different datacenters. Even for the same user, the token may change, but changes should be rare. Also take a look at documentation on authenticating a user with an identity token (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-identity-token). In addition to validate the signing, you should also map the user described by the token (using msexchuid and amurl) to a user on your system. If the amurl changes, one way to handle it is to authenticate the user on your system and reset the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the token with a standard Javascript JWT library (like 'jsonwebtoken'). Just read the x509 cert out of the 'amurl' (from the decoded token; decoding can be done with a JWT library as well) and insert it into a PEM format string like this:

```
  const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

  ...

  let token = 'eyJhbG...';
  let amurl_X509Certificate_value = 'MIIGwz...';
  let verify = jwt.verify(
    token,
    [
      '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----',
      amurl_X509Certificate_value,
      '-----END CERTIFICATE-----',
    ].join('\n'),
    { algorithms: ['RS256'] }
  );
```